# How do I deal with workplace questions regarding personal interests when my main interest may be considered immature?

Tags: professionalism, communication, presentations, non-work-activities

Shortly after starting my new job as a development engineer at a larger company, I was asked to submit some personal information for a slideshow showing recent developments at the workplace (the slideshow runs on a few large screens around the office), and typically has a slide for each recently hired employee, with a picture and description. This is of course informative, but also a chance to promote myself to other employees in the workplace.

One of the things listed in the description that I was asked to submit is about my personal interests outside of work. I immediately list a few of my interests that "look good", such as *a cappella music* and *programming*.

However, my (by far) main interest outside of work is gaming. Among people my age (mid to late 20's), that isn't considered strange, but a majority of the employees are of my parents' generation and may disapprove of *gaming* or *games* as a valid interest.

If I just leave my main interest out I might potentially be missing opportunities to connect with people of similar interests, while putting it in there may make some people think of me as being unprofessional, possibly resulting in me not being considered (perhaps subconsciously) for certain projects.

What is a good way to deal with this situation?

Comment: I think you're worrying over nothing, people the generation ahead of you were the biggest gamers of all time. We saw the start of the gaming industry. Many of us are still gamers. Any gaming presentation would probably be the hit of the party.

Comment: I had had a similar worry at my place of employment, turns out quite a few older people at the company were even bigger gamers than me, if not in the present then definitely when they were my age. I don't think you should put that as your main interest, but it's not something you can't mention, in my opinion.

Comment: I actually strongly agree with the previous commenters. I'm more of a gamer than many of my much younger coworkers, who all seem to like hiking and riding, etc, an anathema to me. :)

Comment: I recently saw a statistic somewhere that today's gamer's average age is 33 years old. So I think you'll be surprised to find that a lot of people twice your age are gaming regularly :) .

Comment: 33 is still quite young by the company standards. I also don't think any of the seniors partake in any digital activities unless forced to (they're more on the industry/chemistry side). But you never know, I may be surprised.

Comment: I'm in my 40's and still a gamer, and I know plenty of others around my age

Comment: I've been in a similar situation, but as a cosplayer.  Nobody understood why a straight man was proudly wearing a mesh shirt, one earring, and a top ponytail.  You are your own person: wear your skin proudly! :-)

Comment: I worked at a small company once that did brown-bag "teambuilding" lunch sessions where members of each team were supposed to present some personal  interest. One of the web developers was into [BDSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BDSM) and he gave a nice 5 minute talk on his interests with some tame G-rated pictures. Some in the office were horrified, some were intrigued, but the brown-bag lunches stopped shortly afterwards.

Comment: "a majority of the employees are of my parents' generation and may disapprove of gaming or games as a valid interest." - A recent highly-acclaimed TV drama depicted *the president of the USA* as a gamer. I think this particular cultural battle may now be regarded as won.

Comment: Some people might disapprove gaming as a valid interest. Other people might disapprove watching sport on TV as a valid interest. A cappella music is even more niche than any of those and is the one most likely to be disapproved. But the real question is: "why should you care" and the answer is "you should not".

Comment: Oh god. Do you work where I work? That board is an abomination born in the deepest depths of hell.

Comment: I'm most likely your parent's generation, and I spend way more time gaming than I should. (computer games, board games, eurogames, etc)

Comment: @Johnny I like to imagine that that developer was the silent hero your company deserved if he talked about that topic specifically to get those "teambuilding" lunches to stop.

Comment: I'd suggest listing 1-2 specific games which you mastered the most. For example: "…competitively playing Chess and Quake 3"

Comment: Just a relevant personal anecdote, that I thought of tonight when out for a business dinner with 5 other colleagues - we had a long discussion about what video games we have played. All of us had played some games in some form or another (though, we reminisced about Unreal Tournament and Starcraft I and not newer games, getting old....). It was a group of people I would not really have expected to have found games. My answer and this question made me think of this when it happened.. :)

Comment: @enderland My closest experience to that is one of my colleagues mentioning his sons sometimes plays "shooting programs", asking if the game I was playing was of that type.

Comment: I agree it's pretty mainstream, but I disagree you should advertise it. I worked with a bunch of old dinosaurs and while they won't think you are weird that may just make them identify you with their children, which in the workplace isn't a good thing. I always hated any work attempt at listing personal interests and would have avoided doing so if possible, or put generic ones (hiking) if I was forced.

Comment: @TechnicalEmployee I agree that I keep essentially all personal info out of the workplace. (Can't do much about my car with purple accents on it though.) I respect and appreciate workplace relationships, but they are not my friends. If they were, we would not have to earn money, right? It would be a family instead.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I think you are worrying too much about this.

If you put in a slide a picture of yourself and perhaps a picture of you singing a cappella you will pretty well cover both groups of people (those who care about video gaming and those who don't).

I suspect that most people who might look down on gaming are very likely to see acapella and find it awesome/cool/great.

Putting a list like:

- a capella singing
- video games
- open source programming

is not at all likely to reflect poorly on you.

Also, keep in mind the benefits of having shared interests. You may alienate say an arbitrary 50% of managers, 25% don't care, but perhaps 25% are also interested - you can immediately form a connection and have talking points. That's beneficial even if it reflects poorly for others.

Comment: +1 I've never had a negative reaction to my own (geeky) hobbies. People seem interested when I tell them I'm a chess master and also that I've invented my own board game. The point of the exercise is to help you bond with your teammates by showing them you are a real person, not just a company resource.

Comment: @user1108 The irony is that you are just a company resource, to be used and thrown out when no longer useful.  At most places at least.

Comment: @user1108 - there's a very different connotation and reception among many people between "gaming as in chess" or even "gaming as a board game", and "gaming as in video games". The former are considered intellectual pursuits worth respect, especially chess. The latter is for - to use Principal Strikland's term - *slackers*.

Comment: @emory Exactly!

Comment: Am I the only one who now wants to know what board game @user1108 has invented?

Comment: @Chips_100: It's not on the market yet (still under development), but its a space pirates game where you shoot your rivals out of the sky and raid planets for loot. Its a good learning experience in design, 3D printing for the pieces and intellectual property law. Patent pending!

Comment: Also by falling into line due to normative pressures, you re-enforce status-quo normativity. By being open about your interests you push back in a small way against marginalisation of them. Do this confidently and you will become a charismatic agent of positive social change. 

This has obvious limits at the margins. When your interests are widely regarded as hateful or causing suffering, this is the point at which pragmatic norms required to have social cohesion begin to outweigh personal preferences. For instance if your main interest is in murdering people.

Comment: @user1108 I for one look forward to the crowd funding campaign!

Comment: @JarrodSmith it depends on context.  for the most part you are right, but if you are in boot camp expressing an interest in fatal violence is re-enforcing status-quo normativity.

Comment: @JarrodSmith I think that the workplace is not for expressing interests, unless they lead to greater income and/or better service. I think this works out better for everyone, as you don't have to consider everyone else's interests while trying to focus on the two goals. The "cogs work better" when there are not so many of them and everyone agrees on what they are for.

Answer (score 39):

It's **extremely unlikely** that anyone will hold an interest in videogames against you. **What you want to avoid is listing it as your only hobby** because, rightly or wrongly, a (perceived) obsessive interest in a single hobby still carries a stigma. It's the same as just listing "watching TV", "reading" or "building model airplanes". Certain people will think that's all you do and consider you immature for not branching out more and only having a single interest.

So, just **list videogames as one of your interests and assume that any person who will hold your choice of hobby against you is not someone you want to interact with much anyway.**

Finally, if you're honestly *that* worried that being known as a gamer could have negative consequences, just leave it out. You're not being asked for an exhaustive list here and there are some environments or cultures where gaming still carries a stigma. You can judge whether your current office is one of those more accurately than strangers on the internet can.

Answer (score 8):

I think at this point most people know computer folks are probably into video games. I remember in college about 80% of people in 100-200 level computer classes are in it solely because they liked video games. They of course change majors once they hit the 300 level courses because it is much harder than they thought.

In the professional world, I wouldn't doubt most people think of IT people playing video games especially in your age group. I had a job interview once where a interviewer straight out asked if I played World of Warcraft and when I said no, he sounded disappointed and went on about how he loved it. I was surprised by this but it is a norm.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't just put you like playing games on there as it's about as interesting as 'I like watching TV'. If there is a facet of gaming that might make people want to connect with you I would be more inclined to discuss that.

i.e. I run a guild of 200 people in X game or I help organise a LAN event etc

Comment: This example would also show a certain amount of management skills such as organisation, scheduling, communication with a lot of people, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You'll never make everybody happy, so I would not worry about people who might not approve. You can't win that battle. But, I might hedge a bit by listing a specific game instead of using the generic term "gaming." If you list "Call of Duty," some people won't know what you are talking about, but they are also the ones most likely to disapprove of it.

Comment: I would actually disagree here. People may have a concern if your main hobby is (virtually) shooting people, versus just 'playing games'. It doesn't matter if to you, CoD _IS_ playing games, it's all perception.

Comment: Good point. I'd have a problem with someone whose hobby is virtually shooting people. If you  can't shoot people in real life, you just don't measure up. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a **lot** older than you, and I would be impressed if you listed gaming as one of your hobbies. In particular, MMO games like World of Warcraft, but many games actually require a lot of skill. For example:

- Resource management: Will I buy the better *sword* or *chest-plate*?
- Time management: Do I have time to do this instance before dinner?
- Being part of a team: Doing your job as part of a group encounter
- Managing a team: Leading a group into a dungeon
- Statistics: Should I get a sword that does 4 damage every 3 seconds or 3 damage every 2 seconds?
- Relationships: Keeping a group working smoothly together
- Finances: Getting the best price at the auction house
- Helping fellow team-members meet performance criteria: "How the hell did the tank die? You were supposed to be healing him!"
- Managing complex requirements: I'm supposed to do *what* here?
- Navigation: "Which way is North, again?"
- Keyboard skills: *Quickly* informing your party of a bunch of incoming monsters
- Dealing with difficult team-members: *Why* did you do that?
- Staying calm under pressure: "Oops, we aggro'ed a patrol - try to stay alive!"

---

> putting it in there may make some people think of me as being unprofessional

I don't think there really is an "unprofessional" hobby.

Comment: Personally, if he lists a MMO, I don't believe he actually has any other hobbies...

Comment: What is this "dinner" of which you seem to think so highly? Hold on - raid starting

Comment: Well, this is an argument why computer gaming SHOULD BE viewed as a positive thing. That doesn't mean that any particular person or group actually does view it as a positive thing.

Comment: If by "unprofessional hobby" you mean one that would make co-workers think less of you, I can think of plenty. Like, experimenting with illegal drugs, or collecting child pornography.

Comment: I'm assuming that you would not list as a "hobby" something that is clearly illegal, like robbing banks. As for whether another person views it positively, I can't speak for all his co-workers, but am saying that as an older person, who used to interview people for positions (and the question was not about a job interview anyway) I would not think negatively of him. You might worry about virtually any hobby, really, like stamp-collecting. At least playing computer games is something to do with computers.

Comment: You could rephrase that as its inverse, i.e. "I don't think there really is a "mature" interest."

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, I doubt many would look down on you because you like video games.

But okay, some people see gamers as creepy fanatics. If you're worried about it, just don't mention it. I can't imagine that the company is going to hire private detectives to investigate if you have any hobbies that you failed to disclose. I really doubt that the purpose here is to trap people into confessing to unsavory hobbies. If someone else in the company knows about your video game addiction and says, "Hey, don't you play a lot of video games? Why didn't you mention that?", you shrug your shoulders and say, "It didn't seem worth mentioning" or "I didn't think of it".

(Anecdote: A few years ago I heard a public service spot on the radio encouraging people to vote. They had some guy with a whiny voice saying, "I spend most of my time playing video games. And my favorite movie is Star Wars." Etc, for a few other geeky interests. Then the narrator comes on and says in an ominous voice, "This guy votes. Shouldn't you?" And I thought, like wow, he sounds a lot like me. Are you saying that people like me are unqualified to vote and, what, that the people who know nothing about science and have no interest in technology should rush to the polls to be sure to outvote us geeks? Seemed pretty bigoted to me.)

Comment: I think the concept of the advert was that the quoted geeky person seemed to focus most of their attention on things other than the shared reality that provides us with food, etc. What opinions is someone likely to base their decisions on if they are not participating in the shared reality most of the time, and their attention is on things that are manifestly "not real"? If that concern is bigoted, then I guess people seem to have this irrational focus on survival and staying comfortable. Hmph!

Answer (score -3):

To make it look more professional, you can write it as 'arcade gaming', or 'gaming review', 'digital action sports gaming', etc.. Finally, now-a-days, IoT (Internet of Things) is getting largely combined with gaming platforms, you can add up something in that way too.. ;-)